# Dual boot with shared data - ext2fs corrupts partition

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, ext4

I want to have the following setup:

- Windows on C: partition (ntfs)
- Linux (Ubuntu) on F: partition (ext4)
- All my files on D: partition (ext4)

My problem is: every time I boot Windows Ext2Fsd corrupts the superblocks of my ext4 partitions. The F: partition got event so bad that all superblocks including backups are gone. (Interestingly, I can access the data from Windows on both corrupt partitions).

I installed the latest version of Ext2Fsd which is supposed to fix the bug but apparently it didn't (I repaired the partition, started Windows and then Linux live USB stick -- corrupt again).

How can I get Windows and Linux to play along nicely?

**Edit:**

Suddenly Ext2Fsd recognizes both partitions as ext3, which is wrong, so I can't access the data in Windows anymore (this might change with the next reboot).

Other things I tried: I had `D:` as ntfs before, but Ubuntu said something like "Windows did not shut down correctly, can only mount in read-only" (and some quick research couldn't fix it). I'm fine with reformatting my Data partition again if it helps though (I still have a backup of the original NTFS partition).

Comment: A workaround may be to use NTFS on the D: partition where all your files are that you are sharing between Windows and Linux. My experience with Linux is the NTFS interface works fine. Is there a reason you are choosing ext4 for the shared partition?

Comment: Yes, the partition was NTFS previously and I only got read-only for some reasons and I couldn't get it to work in a reasonable amount of time so I thought switching to ext4 would help. (Especially since I made good experience with Ext2Fsd with my raspberry pi and other Linux live drives)